# Multiple XOR operations

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

> Find $8$ distinct $8$-bit numbers, each with $4$ bits set to one, such that the cumulative XOR of these bytes is $10101010$.

I imagine there are multiple answers, so the first correct answer wins the prestigious check mark.

For non-mathmo's,

- $0 \operatorname{XOR} 0=0$
- $0 \operatorname{XOR} 1 = 1$
- $1 \operatorname{XOR} 0 = 1$
- $1 \operatorname{XOR} 1 = 0$

$\operatorname{XOR}$ is commutative, and therefore the question wants an even number of bits set in columns that result in $0$, and an odd number of bits set in columns that result in a $1$.

For example,

```
1 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1
-------
1 0 0 1
```

Comment: When first reading "4 bit set" I was thinking of a set of 4 bits. I suggested an edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution:

> ```
>  Number    Cumulative
>  11110000  11110000
>  00111100  11001100
>  00001111  11000011
>  11101000  00101011
>  11000011  11101000
>  00101101  11000101
>  11000101  00000000
>  10101010  10101010
> ```

Strategy:

> 1) Try to reach 0 after 7 numbers.  That way, number 8 is simply the final number.
>
>  2) To reach 0 after 7 numbers, I make sure that at each step up to step 6, my cumulative value has 4 bits.  Then, number 7 will be the cumulative value, to erase all 4 bits and leave 0.
>
>  3) To maintain 4 bits, at each step I erase 2 existing bits and set 2 new bits.  I just need to make sure not to repeat any numbers, by using a new pair of bits each time.

Answer (score 5):

> If there are 8 numbers with 4 ones in each, there must be 32 ones in total. You can do it like this: 
> 11110000
> 01111000
> 00111100
> 00011110
> 00001111
> 10000111
> 11000011
> 11100001
>  The XOR of these 8 will be 00000000, but we can easily fix it by switching around some bits of the 2nd number: 
> 11110000
> **1**1**0**1**0**0**1**0
> 00111100
> 00011110
> 00001111
> 10000111
> 11000011
> 11100001 
>  Note that switching around entire odd/even-numbered columns also works (odd with odd, even with even).

Comment: your solution is better than mine

Comment: Because of the nice and symmetrical way you have constructed this answer, I just cannot help wondering: what on earth made you choose the **second** number as the target for the final step, when any other would have worked just as well? :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

> ```
> 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
> 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
> 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
> 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
> 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
> 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
> 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
> 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1
> ```

Comment: Boo! I will have it known that I got there ahead of JS1 by _thirteen whole seconds_. (Seriously, of course it's fine that JS1 got the coveted green checkmark -- their answer offers a specific strategy and mine doesn't -- because my approach was very ad hoc and it didn't seem worth trying to describe what was in my head as I did it.)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (ninjaed):

> ```
> 1- 11110000
> 2- 01111000
> 3- 00111100
> 4- 00011110
> 5- 00001111
>
> 6- 10010110
> 7- 00110011 
>
> 8- 10101010
> ```

Strategy (not so illuminating nor useful I think):

> I wrote down numbers 1 to 5 by shifting a 4-bit block of consecutive ones - there is no particular reason to do it, I just did so to write down 5 different numbers out of 8 quickly. Then I used number 6 and 7 to cancel the cumulative xor so that number 8 can just be the required solution.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
> 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0
> 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
> 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0
> 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
> 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
> 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
> 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
> ---------------
> 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
> ```